What layers do I need to build a production yocto image?
Working through the Yocto docs and they all say "poky is for reference build your own distro." I was able to get something working including only openembedded-core. I read somewhere though that meta-openembedded is a subset of that so I added meta-openembedded/oe-core and removed openembedded-core. Now bitbake-layers show-layers just hangs at NOTE: Starting bitbake server... Can anyone shed a little light on my situation please?

The reason behind hanging could be an instance is already running. You can check it with ps x.

Found it in meta-openembedded/meta-oe/README.md:
This layer depends on:
URI: git://github.com/openembedded/openembedded-core.git
branch: scarthgap
